# Pull JSON array (from Overpass API) to PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I would like to integrate OSM data into my Postgresql/PostGIS database automatically (trigger-like operation) using Overpass API.

For my tests I have selected the following query:

```
https://www.overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=[out:json];node[amenity=bicycle_rental](46.1138,-1.1630,46.1925,-1.1511);out meta;
```

Is there any documentation associated with this type of use? I haven't found anything so far except the following Postgresql documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/functions-json.html

And this Q&A simply redirects the discussion to the use of QuickOSM: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/46360/overpass-api-to-postgresql

I asked about the possibilities offered by foreign data wrappers: https://github.com/nkhorman/json_fdw

But how it works and the automation of a recovery script doesn't seem very clear to me.

Comment: Technically, you can have a trigger that makes an http request and process its output (search for "postgres trigger http request")... though you will find a lot of pages telling why it is a bad idea. I would personally put this in the app/website code, not in the DB

Comment: Why not download the area you want and load it into postgis? calling an api to do this will get your ip blocked quickly.

Comment: updated OSM downloads available http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html